# How to create a scalable Architecture

Tags: web-applications, web, architecture

We are suppose to create an Web Application for an startup, so how to proceed about it.
Which stack to choose and how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly being a startup, speed of coding is important for you, so I would recommend PHP as a backend for web.
You should try to use a service oriented architecture(SOA), which would basically become the one source of truth for all your web application.

So if you can create proper Api's your application is safe for future. If let say a month later you are unhappy with MYSQL performance, just switch the backend database. Nothing is to be changes in PHP code, as api remains same.

Second you need 3 DB servers tomorrow for API, so its the concern of API server, not your web architecture.

Use NGINX and PHP-FPM, instead of apache mod-php , it may take some additional config just refer [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-7) or any new if you can find one.

Redis is quite good and stable with key value data. Use MongoDB for any non transactional data and any ACID complaint DB for transactional one like MYSQL, POSTFRESQL, ORACLE etc.

Use a basic load balancer like HA-PROXY, try to configure it manually instead of buying expensive hardware.

Try to host on AWS, first year is free. Use a dedicated server. You will find everything in AWS.

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding !!!